# unable to convert systrace to html using puthon2 and git

Tags: android, logging, systrace

after taking systrace using adb , unable to convert in html file in android pie device

MX0004117@MMXITD0210-106 MINGW64 ~
$ git clone https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult.git
fatal: destination path 'catapult' already exists and is not an empty directory.

MX0004117@MMXITD0210-106 MINGW64 ~
$ python2 catapult/systrace/bin/systrace --from-file=C:\Users\MX0004117\Desktop\ap\S.ctrace
bash: python2: command not found

MX0004117@MMXITD0210-106 MINGW64 ~
$

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this error **fatal: destination path 'catapult' already exists and is not an empty directory** by just closing cmd or any other file containing catapult-project.
And for this **python2: command not found**, just add python2 in environment variable.

And for converting `.ctrace` file to `.html`, use this command

`cd /path-to-traces-on-my-dev-machine && \ systrace --from-file trace-file-name.ctrace`